# Multi-page apps in QML

Tags: android, ios, qt, qml

I've been asked to create an app for a client which could potentially be on both android and iOS (concentrating on iOS first). So I thought that Qt may be the answer. I would like to use Qt Quick to create the app but I can't seem to find a way to efficiently handle multiple pages, baring in mind that each page could be fairly heavyweight.

So far I've tried:

- Pagination with loaders i.e. dynamically pulling in the needed screen. This works but there is a noticeable delay the first time a screen is loaded
- Making each page a component and showing only the necessary screen. This loads all pages on startup which is too memory heavy
- Making each page a component and displaying them through a ListView. Same problem as above.

There has to be a middle ground where views can essentially go to a low memory mode like in native iOS apps. Any suggestions welcome.

NOTE: The progression of the screens is not necessarily linear

Comment: Have you tried switching states?

Comment: @Kakadu when you say switching states what do you mean?

Comment: These states: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-statesanimations-states.html

Answer (score 2):

My experience with QML is rather limited but from other UX experiences I would think the solution would involve re-factoring your pages to utilize the [Loader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html) item for their inner children/Components. From what I read it sounds like you are using the [Loader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html) item on each page itself.

For example, when your program starts load in your pages, it should be pretty light on memory otherwise there many still be large components that need to be dynamically loaded.

When the user provides input to go to a specific page, animate/show as you would normally which shouldn't be delayed. The page itself should then utilize a [Loader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html) item for each component that needs to be loaded (i.e. ones with large memory footprints).

While components are loading you could show a progress bar/wheel animation. Once the component has finished loading via the [onLoaded signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html#onLoaded-signal) you can hide the progress bar/wheel.

You may also want to look at the [Loader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html) item's [asynchronous property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html#asynchronous-prop) to ensure any animation (i.e. the progress bar/wheel) while the component loads avoid glitches.

Finally when the page needs to be hidden simply set each [Loader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html) item's [active property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html#active-prop) to false and it should release the loaded component.

Hope that helps and isn't repeating something you've already tried.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is pretty much what I've tried, showing a loading dialog when loading pages is a pretty bad UX. I wouldn't need to do this for a native iOS application and that is what I'm trying to emulate i.e. the same kind of user experience that you would get from a native app. It could be a product of the framework being fairly new on mobile platforms that a decent paging strategy doesn't exist yet!?

Comment: I've used a few iOS applications that take time when loading a page and show a progress animation after selecting an option. I don't think it's entirely uncommon to delay showing a page's contents while the component is loaded or data is fetched. :) Hope the project goes well!

Comment: Cheers. I could understand if there was a http request or something that was loading data but for a native app with no network dependencies the UI loading is pretty much instantaneous. I think I'll have a look at writing a paging framework myself that is pretty dynamic but smart enough to know which views to hold in memory and which to not hold. I'll check back in here if I do, in the mean time, any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: These are basic QML `Item` objects that you are using or are they loading in large images/sound/etc...?

Comment: Each page will have varying numbers of images, ranging from 4 or 5 up to more than a hundred (in a carousel type widget)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but `Qt.Controls`'s [`StackView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html) has support for pushing and popping with various animations.

As the previous answers indicate, using a [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) is also an option but it doesn't let you easily animate the change (when changing views, the old and new are not available at the same time so you can't do nice animations).

An alternative is to use `Component`s, lazily instantiate views and animate the transitions. Check out the example in by QtWS 2015 talk, slides and code [available here](https://www.kdab.com/kdab-at-qt-world-summit/).